# Exception in loading Skin

Tags: java, exception, look-and-feel

I'm using SkinLookAndFeel and want to use the aqua theme pack of SkinLookAndFeel. I've downloaded sklf.jar and aquathemepack.zip. Here is my code:

```
        Skin skin = SkinLookAndFeel.loadSkin("aquathemepack.zip");
        SkinLookAndFeel.setSkin(skin);
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SkinLookAndFeel());
```

and the exception is:

```
java.lang.Exception: Unable to load this skin file:/C:/Workspaces/Demo_Swing/Demo/aquathemepack.zip (by using filename matching),  try an explicit constructor
    at com.l2fprod.gui.plaf.skin.SkinLookAndFeel.loadSkin(SkinLookAndFeel.java:902)
    at com.l2fprod.gui.plaf.skin.SkinLookAndFeel.loadSkin(SkinLookAndFeel.java:883)
    at com.talk.Atalk.<init>(Atalk.java:139)
    at com.talk.Atalk.main(Atalk.java:1214)
```

Why I'm getting this error? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have solved it.

Instead of using `loadSkin()` I use `loadThemePack()` and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `SkinLookAndFeel.loadSkin(String)` method expects a file name that ends with either "gtkrc" or ".themerc".  The source code is [here](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/com/l2fprod/gui/plaf/skin/SkinLookAndFeel.java.html) ... is you want to take a look.